# Extract text from Microsoft Word with final version track changes using Python?

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

```
import win32com.client

def function( Directory ) :
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch( 'Word.Application' )
    doc = app.Documents.Open( Directory )
    text = doc.Content.Text
    app.Quit()
```

I am using this code to extract contents from Microsoft Word docs but it extracts the "Final Showing Markup" version.  I only want to extract contents of the "Final" version.  Is there a way to do this using pywin32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc.ShowRevisions=0
```

Nevermind, I got it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pywin32, but as an alternative you cold extract the whole thing each time and pass them to git. This would give you a full history of changes between versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I figured it out by using the Word library